# Writing to a TextFile in Java

Tags: java, string, text

Hi there I'm trying to write strings to a textfile but there is a little problem. I completed my code with the help of the other questions at this site but when i try to add strings to a text file it erases everything in that text file and writes the input. But I want it to go to the nextline and write it. I couldn't solve it. I would appreciate any help. Thank you..

```
public static void addCar() throws IOException{

        String string = transferBrand;
        String string2 = ":"+transferModel;
        System.out.println(string+string2);
        File file = new File("HatchBack.txt");
        try {
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(string+string2);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(stringReader);
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            for(String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null; line =bufferedReader.readLine()) {               
                bufferedWriter.write(line);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();                   
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(untested) Did you try this as mentioned in JavaDoc?

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
```

Comment: Well that was pretty easy I can't believe how i didn't see that Thank you it works now :/

Comment: Sometimes man does not to see the wood for the trees :)
Just mark the answer as solution to close the question.